# Show that $U_{26}/\langle 5\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

There are a lot of typos in Hungerford's Intro Algebra and it seems like this is another one. $|U_{26}| = 12$ and in the set of units under multiplication, $|\langle 5\rangle| = 3$. So the quotient group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ not $\mathbb{Z}
_{3}$.

I was thinking I was incorrect in considering the powers of $5$ for the generating subgroup that are in $U_{26}$, but that is what an example shows in the exposition of Section $8.3$.

Comment: The typo is $\lvert\langle 5\rangle\rvert=4$ not $3$: $5^2=-1$ so $5^4=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/26\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $1$,$ 5$, and $25$? What is the fourth?

Comment: $-5+26\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think I understand. $21 \in $ the generating subgroup?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the first powers of $5\bmod26$:
$$\begin{array}{c|crrr}
\hline
k &1&2&3&\phantom{-}4&\phantom{-}5\\
\hline
5^k&5&-1&-5&\phantom{-}1&5\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
So the subroup generated by $5$ has order $4$, and in the isomorphism $\;U_{26}\simeq \mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$, the subgroup $\langle\mkern1.5mu 5\mkern1.5mu\rangle$ corresponds to the (additive) subgroup $3\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$, so that the quotient
$$U_{26}/\langle\mkern1.5mu 5\mkern1.5mu\rangle\simeq (\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z)\big/(3\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z)\simeq \mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$$
by the third isomorphism theorem.